# List all posts in custom post type by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Is there a way I can list all posts in a specific custom post type and arrange them by the custom taxonomy term attached to them?

For example;

**Taxonmy Term #1**
Post Type
Post Type
Post Type

**Taxonomy Term #2**
Post Type
Post Type

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('custom_taxonomy');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
```

We get all the terms of a taxonomy, loop through them, and fire off a title link to each post that belongs to that term. If you need to reorder the taxonomy terms, you can do so with a plugin pretty easily. [Reorder Taxonomy](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/),  I believe. **But** pay attention that this plugin adds(!) another column to your table on *activation* and **does not remove it upon deactivation**!

Comment: Hi @GhostToast This works great, I have a direct question, how can I filter this by taxonomy, I have tennis, golf, soccer, voleyball, this codes brings them all with their post that have the taxonomy checked, How can I filter to only show the Soccer Taxonomy with its posts.

Comment: @RodrigoZuluaga that would be a basic single query then. take away `$custom_terms` and the `foreach()` and just define `'terms'` manually to the slug or whatever you want.

Comment: I got it little different I think but your code hell good
$args = array('post_type' => 'publica',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'comision-publicaciones',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => array($ter_name)
            ),
        ),
     );

Answer (score 2):

Not a particularly elegant solution but you can create multiple queries each for the specific terms and then output them. Hopefully someone can come up with a nicer way of automatically pulling the terms to modify the output/sorting. But this would get you going.

```
<?php

//First Query for Posts matching term1
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_1',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'term1' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    echo 'All posts found in ' . $term->name;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //Output what you want
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}

//RESET YOUR QUERY VARS
wp_reset_query();

//Second Query for term2
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_1',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'term2' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    echo 'All posts found in ' . $term->name;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //Output what you want
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice one! GhostOne's solution was what I had been looking for. 
In my situation the custom post type was 'minining_accidents' and custom taxonomies associated with this was 'accident-types' which had multiple terms under it. My idea was to create a custom widget to show list of posts under terms in this custom taxonomies. In my trial run it got what I wanted. Rest was spruce up. Here is my code:

```
function fn_get_list_of_mining_accident_types()
{
    $custom_taxonomy='accident-types';  
    $custom_terms = get_terms($custom_taxonomy);    
    $str_return='<ul>';
    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) 
    {
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'minining_accidents',
            'tax_query' => array(               
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );  

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        $term_name=$custom_term->name;
        $term_slug=$custom_term->slug;
        $term_link=get_term_link($term_slug, $custom_taxonomy);

        $str_return.='<li><a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';

        if($loop->have_posts()) 
        {
            $str_return.='<ol>';

            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $str_return.='<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li> ';
            endwhile;

            $str_return.='</ol>';           
         }
         $str_return.='</li>';
    }
    $str_return.='</ul>';
    return $str_return;
}
```

Yes! There always is an option to further improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is long solution i tried before coming to this thread. Hope this may help someone to understand better.

```
        <?php
    // Get list of all taxonomy terms  -- In simple categories title
    $args = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order'   => 'ASC'
            );
    $cats = get_categories($args);

    // For every Terms of custom taxonomy get their posts by term_id
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
            <?php echo $cat->name; ?> <br>
            <?php // echo $cat->term_id; ?> <br>
        </a>


            <?php
                // Query Arguments
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'portfolio', // the post type
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'project_category', // the custom vocabulary
                            'field'    => 'term_id',          // term_id, slug or name  (Define by what you want to search the below term)    
                            'terms'    => $cat->term_id,      // provide the term slugs
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                // The query
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    echo '<h2> List of posts tagged with this tag </h2>';

                    echo '<ul>';
                    $html_list_items = '';
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        $html_list_items .= '<li>';
                        $html_list_items .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                        $html_list_items .= get_the_title();
                        $html_list_items .= '</a>';
                        $html_list_items .= '</li>';
                    }
                    echo $html_list_items;
                    echo '</ul>';

                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

                wp_reset_postdata(); // reset global $post;

                ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: omg thank you! I should have tried this first.

Answer (score -1):

To show a list of custom posts from a custom taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-custom-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'your-term' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
     while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //Output what you want      
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
}
```

Title

- List item
- List item
- List item