# Listing posts under primary and secondary taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

#### Following on from this post:

[List all posts in custom post type by taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/list-all-posts-in-custom-post-type-by-taxonomy?newreg=c243730514684300a35e30a4d701d456)

How would I go about doing the same as above with a Custom Post Type called *Area*, but looping through the child-categories to get something like:

- **Primary Area**

  - Post
  - Post

  - **Secondary/Child Area**

    - Post

    - Post

    - Post

Answer (score 0):

This only takes care of two levels. You could make a recursive function, if you have 'unlimited' levels.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('custom_taxonomy');

/**
 * Loop through all taxonomies
 */
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term):

    // Reset query (for good measures sake)
    wp_reset_query();

    // Set the args (getting ready to get posts that are in the given taxonomy)
    $outer_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                'post_parent' => 0   // This means that it's only top-level taxonomies included
            )
          )
       );

    // Get the information for the outer loop.
    $outer_loop = new WP_Query( $outer_args );

    if($outer_loop->have_posts()):
      echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

      // Loop through outer loop    
      while( $outer_loop->have_posts() ): 
        $outer_loop->the_post(); 
        $outer_loop_ID = get_the_ID();

        // Display OUTER loop info: 
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';


        /**
         * Inner loop
         */
        wp_reset_query();
        $inner_args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                  'post_parent' => $outer_loop_ID   // This gets the posts that has the outer loops post as parent
              )
           )
        );

        $inner_loop = new WP_Query($inner_args);
        if($inner_loop->have_posts()):

          // Display inner loop information
          echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';
          while($inner_loop->have_posts()) : 
            $inner_loop->the_post();

             // Display INNER loop info: 
             echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';

          endwhile; // Inner loop 

        endif; // if($inner_loop->have_posts()) {

      endwhile; // Outer loop

   endif; // if($outer_loop->have_posts()):

endforeach; // foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term):
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned I'm using this as a partial to include on the homepage.

Comment: Also I'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /app/public/wp-content/themes/toolkit/homepage.php

Comment: I missed a semi-colon after `get_the_ID()`. I've just updated the code. Try that?

Comment: now throwing an error down at the endwhile

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /app/public/wp-content/themes/toolkit/homepage.php

Comment: Baah! Missed an `endif`. Try now?

Comment: Sorry, still getting an error, this time on the endif! :D

Comment: is it missing an endforeach?

Comment: I just tried making the code a bit prettier and fixed a couple of this. Try now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88407/discussion-between-sketchybear-and-zeth).